# Are the Imperial projects listed by Jyn Erso related to anything previously seen?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, rogue-one

During the battle of Scarif when Jyn is trying to find the Death Star Plans and is reading out project names, one of the names was **Black Saber.**

What were some of the other names she rattled off and do they have any relation to any objects or superweapons in canon or legends? Or could they be nods to other sci-fi superweapons?

Structural Engineering: Project Code Names

- Stellar Sphere
- Mark Omega
- Pax Aurora
- War Mantle
- Cluster Prism
- Black Saber
- Star Dust - Death Star

Comment: Pretty sure it said Blacksaber. Still may be the same.

Comment: looks like it was Blacksaber from Jason Baker post about the novel, updated question

Comment: Blacksaber made me think of Dark Saber too.

Comment: Black Saber immediately made me think of the [Eclipse Super Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eclipse_(Eclipse-class)). The timeline seems to check out too. However, I can find no evidence that they are actually related.

Answer (score 19):

From the novelization, these are the Imperial projects listed by Jyn (emphasis mine):

> She spoke sternly, demanding Cassian's attention as she read from the screen. "Project code names: **Stellarsphere. Mark Omega. Pax Aurora**..." Were all of them weapons like the Death Star, designed for terror and genocide? Had her father known about the others? She couldn't afford to think about it — there were too many horrors down that road. "**War-Mantle. Cluster-Prism. Black-Saber**."
>
> *[...]*
>
> "**Stardust**,"
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Chapter 19</sup>

Despite some superficial naming similarities, to my knowledge there's been no confirmed link between any of these projects and any existing (canon or legends) property. The prequel novel *Catalyst* implies that at least a few of them are actually subcomponents of the Death Star itself:

> The Imperial Energy Division was new, but it, too, operated under the umbrella of Project Celestial Power. In fact, each separate department of the battle station project had its own cover name and cover agency, and Galen wasn't alone in working for a counterfeit division and having his research put to alternative uses. Scattered across the galaxy were teams of scientists working on conventional weaponry, tractor beam and hyperdrive technology, even hull cladding systems. Each project was concealed behind names like *Stellar Sphere*, *Mark Omega*, and *Pax Aurora*. But all those paled in comparison with research on the superlaser.
>
> <sup>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel* Chapter 19: "Closed Interval"</sup>

Comment: Damn guess I heard what i wanted to hear :p, thanks updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Could project **black-saber** be referring to the Darksaber? The ancient Jedi light-saber stolen by the Mandalorians and used by Pre Vizsla, Darth Maul and Sabine Wren?

[image: black-saber]

We know that Emperor Palpatine was aware of the blade because of the dual he had with Darth Maul in Clone Wars. Which would explain a s

[image]

And we also know now that Sabine Wren is the last wielder of the blade (that we know of) prior to it being mentioned in Rogue One. This is thanks to *Trials of the Darksaber* in Rebels.

[image]

Comment: black saber does not necessarily equal dark saber so we can't say it was mentioned in Rogue One until there is further evidence

Comment: I meant to put "mentioned" in quotes ;) Just a theory.

Answer (score -1):

For full explanations, check out Star Wars Explained's video. Here are the brief summaries:

1. Stellar Sphere- Starkiller base.
2. Mark Omega. I totally forgot this one.
3. Pax Aurora- Satellite array (Dawn Of Peace is what Pax Aurora stands for.)
4. War Mantle- The World Devastators
5. Cluster Prism- Another kyber crystal thingy.
6. Black Saber- Super Laser carrying ship known as "The Darksaber". Essentially Death Star's laser in a shell.     The full video is here:

Comment: What are the sources? Where does the video get those from?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - do you know if the video is just marketing material, or is part of a Disney-official canon?

Answer (score -2):

A couple seem to refer to non canonical elements of the star wars universe, and one canonical. Project black saber is likely referring to the black light saber, I think it was seen in the clone wars cartoon. I SUSPECT that it will make an appearance in 8, but we will see.

The other 2 that I noticed I am habing a hard time remembering the names of, but they bring a lot of hope and excitement. One was the name of a planet. The planet that the HK droids made their last stand on, and where Vader OFFICIALLY  banned their continuation. If they plan to bring those back, that opens a fair amount of my favorite parts of the stat wars universe to come back, specifically the SWKOTOR series.

The 3rd... I'm unsure about. A friend spoke of it..  but I know nothing about it. Apparently one was the name of a zombie virus that the empire made as a bio weapon.

Comment: This answer could benefit from some references

Answer (score -2):

Well actually, there's a good chance that project Black-Saber is referring to the superweapon Darksaber, an imperial dreadnought built around a copy of the Death Star's main gun. Also, it's possible that cluster prism is talking about the Maw installation run by Admiral Natasi Daala.

Comment: canon sources for any of this?

Answer (score -2):

What about the star destroyer superweapon that was developed in the MAW? It launches torpedos into active suns and makes them go supernova.

Comment: Are you asking a new question or trying to answer this question with an example?

Comment: I think the example you mention is the ["Sun Crusher"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_Crusher).   But how does that relate to the question.  do you have any evidence that it is one of the projects mentioned?