# The Scarif Archives names

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

The names in the Scarif Archives seem to lead to the Death Star, for every single name in the Archives (that is said aloud in the movie) seems to have a relevance to the Death Star as we know it. Stellarsphere means star-sized-sphere, Mark Omega means the Biggest mark, Pax Aurora means peaceful dawn and also War-Mantle, Cluster-Prism(the laser itself) and Black-Saber(a black light-saber), and also the Stardust, the last one is what remains after the Death Star finishes with its mark.

Were these names sketches for the Death Star in early development (outside the universe)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking? Are you asking if the names were alternate names for Death Star?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147548/31051?

Comment: @JasonBaker - it's closely related, but I think at its core different. It's asking if they are all names for Death Star, and specifically about the important "Stardust" name

Comment: I'm asking if those names are actually variations of the same project (out of universe mostly) since they pretty much mean the same thing. An implied huge sphere that destroys things with a laser. @DVK-in-exile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking if these are the alternate names of Death Star, then ***no***.

They seem to be separate **projects**, based on Alexander Freed's official RO novelization:

> She spoke sternly, demanding Cassian’s attention as she read from the screen.   **“Project code names: Stellarsphere. Mark Omega. Pax Aurora…” Were all of them weapons like the Death Star, designed for terror and genocide**? Had her father known about the others? She couldn’t afford to think about it—there were too many horrors down that road. “War-Mantle. Cluster-Prism. Black-Saber.”
>   (*Chapter 19*)

Note that these were code names for ***different projects***, with different physical cartridges - not simply discarded names from Name-This-DS1-project game:

> The cartridge was unlabeled, no different from any other. No different from the thousands surrounding her, except that her father had given his life to reveal it.
>   She wedged a boot against the stack for leverage, **set a free hand on the handle of Mark Omega or Pax Aurora or Heartchopper or whatever ghastly thing the Empire’s scientists had thought up, and tugged at Stardust in the hand of the machine**. The frozen arm clung tight; then she jerked the tape away and the arm bobbed loosely in the air.

However, [as this answer by Jason Baker indicates](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147612/976), they may possibly have been separate projects that were covering pieces of technology in DS sub-components (tractor beams, hyperdrive etc...)

---

Ironically, you were right to pick up the point that "Stardust" name is special, though your guess was wrong as to why. Stardust has **nothing to do** with what remains after Death Star shoots. **It's an affectionate childhood nickname Galen had for his daughter Jyn.**

> “I love you, Stardust.”
>   “I love you, too, Papa.”
>   (*Prologue*)
>
> Papa looked at her kindly. Jyn thought she’d surprised him, in a good way. “Stardust. Don’t ever change.”
>   (*Chapter 3*)

and that's how she knew which file she needed:

> And she stopped.
>   The next name stood out with burning intensity, so obvious she might have found it by touch.
>   “What?” Cassian asked.
>   **“Stardust,” Jyn said. “It’s that one.”**
>   “How do you know that?” Curiosity and urgency mixed in his voice, as if he wanted to say: Be sure.
>   **Jyn was sure. “I know because it’s me.”**
>   Cassian looked at her with astonishment. Then he turned back to the console, gripped the controls fiercely. “Kay, we need the file for Stardust!”
>   (*Chapter 19*)

Comment: I know the significance of Stardust and why she knew it was the plan for the Death Star but the other names seem to be variations of names for the Death Star since they all mean quite the same thing with different words.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin - you expect **imagination** from a bunch of Imperial bureaucrats? :)

Comment: i expect imagination from the same people that brought us 7 more movies based on a floating sphere of death.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin - heh :)